# How to sum value of two json object key?

Tags: javascript, json

```
"bills": [
    {
        "refNo": 17,
        "billDate": "1-apr-2016",
        "dueDate": "30-apr-2016",
        "pendingAmount": 4500,
        "overdueDays": 28
    },
    {
        "refNo": 20,
        "billDate": "15-apr-2016",
        "dueDate": "3-may-2016",
        "pendingAmount": 56550,
        "overdueDays": 15
    }
]
```

I want to sum "pendingAmount" field.
It should be return like pendingAmount: 61050

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` and then `Array#reduce` to flatten your object and then sum the result of the map :

```
bills.map(bill => bill.pendingAmount).reduce((acc, amount) => acc + amount);
```

here's a snippet :

```js
var bills = [
          {
            "refNo": 17,
            "billDate": "1-apr-2016",
            "dueDate": "30-apr-2016",
            "pendingAmount": 4500,
            "overdueDays": 28
          },
          {
            "refNo": 20,
            "billDate": "15-apr-2016",
            "dueDate": "3-may-2016",
            "pendingAmount": 56550,
            "overdueDays": 15
          }
        ];
var res = bills.map(bill => bill.pendingAmount).reduce((acc, amount) => acc + amount);
console.log(res)
```

Hope it helps,

Best regards,

Answer (score 6):

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
var bills = [
          {
            "refNo": 17,
            "billDate": "1-apr-2016",
            "dueDate": "30-apr-2016",
            "pendingAmount": 4500,
            "overdueDays": 28
          },
          {
            "refNo": 20,
            "billDate": "15-apr-2016",
            "dueDate": "3-may-2016",
            "pendingAmount": 56550,
            "overdueDays": 15
          }
        ];
        
        
      var result = bills.reduce(function(_this, val) {
          return _this + val.pendingAmount
      }, 0);

    console.log(result)
    //61050 answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following snippet:

```
var sum = JSON.parse(bills).reduce(function(acc, val){
  return acc.pendingAmount + val.pendingAmount;
}, {pendingAmount: 0});
```

it uses the array.prototype.reduce() function on the parsed JSON. The second argument of the reduce is the initial value passed to the reduce function

Comment: Might be this code resolve the problem.add proper description in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner with some ES2015 destructuring:

```
json.bills.reduce(({pendingAmount: a}, {pendingAmount: b})=> a+b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
let sum, billsPOJO;

billsPOJO = YOURJSON.bills;

sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; billsPOJO.length; i++) {
 sum += billsPOJO[i].pendingAmount; 
}
```

Comment: Its a whole lot of work to do. Why do this if JS mainly ES6 is giving you shorthand & oneliner way to achieve this!