# How to find the sum of priceLakh in one line?

Tags: javascript, arrays

var myCars=[{
"name": "Axio",
"priceLakh":22.5
},
{
"name": "Axio0",
"priceLakh":22.5
},
{
"name": "Axio00",
"priceLakh":22.5
},
{
"name": "Axio000",
"priceLakh":22.5
},]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum value of two json object key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436041/how-to-sum-value-of-two-json-object-key)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `reduce`

```js
var myCars=[{ "name": "Axio", "priceLakh":22.5 }, { "name": "Axio0", "priceLakh":22.5 }, { "name": "Axio00", "priceLakh":22.5 }, { "name": "Axio000", "priceLakh":22.5 },]

const sum = myCars.reduce((res, {priceLakh}) => res + priceLakh, 0 )

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` loop to calculate the sum.

```js
var myCars=[{ "name": "Axio", "priceLakh":22.5 }, { "name": "Axio0", "priceLakh":22.5 }, { "name": "Axio00", "priceLakh":22.5 }, { "name": "Axio000", "priceLakh":22.5 }],sum=0;

myCars.forEach(element => {sum=sum+element.priceLakh;});

console.log("₹"+sum+" Lakhs")
```

Comment: Doesn't look like one line to me.

Comment: It's one line only i just formatted in a proper way.

Comment: It really is not. You're defining a variable for it and then manipulate it. It's 2 lines at best. One line means a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. The reduce operator and destructuring feature

```js
var myCars = [
  { name: "Axio", priceLakh: 22.5 },
  { name: "Axio0", priceLakh: 22.5 },
  { name: "Axio00", priceLakh: 22.5 },
  { name: "Axio000", priceLakh: 22.5 },
];

var answer = myCars.reduce((partialSum, {priceLakh}) => partialSum + priceLakh, 0);

console.log(answer);
```